# From keyword not found where expected error in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, keyword, execution

```
Select firstname as name, time as asof, salary as bal into temp employee
from people.person p
where p.id =1;
```

Need to create a temporary table employee by inserting values from already created table person which belongs to people database but getting error from keyword not found where expected

Comment: `into temp` is PL/SQL. Do you mean a real (already existing) [temporary table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-6EB347F0-64BA-4B15-8182-41BA7D5A876F), or one you want to create from this data? Or a CTE, for the duration of another statement? Or something else? It might help to explain how you plan to use it.

Comment: If you do really mean a temporary table then you should create that once, and then populate it (`insert .... into ... select ....`) as needed in each session. But it isn't clear what you are really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd then use CTAS (Create Table As Select), not an invalid `INTO` clause; it is used for different purposes.

```
create table temp_employee as
  select firstname as name,
         time as asof,
         salary as bal
  from people.person p
  where p.id = 1;
```

---

Based on comment you posted, there are several options you might want to consider.

One is to create a *permanent* table (just like the above example shows). If you'll reuse it, then - in your procedure - first delete its contents (or truncate the table as it is way faster), and then re-populate it:

```
delete from temp_employee;
-- or truncate table temp_employee;

insert into temp_employee
  select firstname, time, salary from people.person
  where id = 1;
```

Another option is to create a *true* temporary table, e.g.

```
create global temporary table temp_employee
  (name     varchar2(30),
   time     date,
   bal      number
  )
on commit preserve rows;
```

Whenever you need data in it, just insert it:

```
insert into temp_employee (name, time, bal)
select firstname as name,
       time as asof,
       salary as bal
from people.person p
where p.id = 1;
```

Doing so, its contents will be visible only to you (and nobody else), while table's contents will be kept during the transaction or session (it depends on how you created it - see the `on commit preserve/delete rows` clause).

What you should **not** do is to create the table, drop it, then create it again, and so on - in Oracle, we create table once and use it many times.

Comment: By creating table like this it's creating permanent table ,so while executing the statement again it's throwing error table already exist, I need to create temporary table employee which will have the same columns as person table(which is a permanent table).Need to put this query in my python method.

Comment: @munia, You have to use a DROP table syntax first by checking whether the table exists or not. If it exists then drop it else create a permanent table.

Comment: Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: @Littlefoot while executing in the above format it's throwing missing keyword error . Modified the query like below and it's working fine . create global temporary table temp_employee on commit preserve rows as select name,time as asof, salary as bal from people.person p where p.id=1 but the problem is same it's creating permanent table hence when executing the query for the second time it's throwing error like name is already used by an existing object

Comment: In Oracle, a *global temporary table* is still a "permanent" object in the database, it won't "disappear" (at the end of the session, for example) - you'd have to drop it. Therefore, yes - if you tried to create it once again, you got the error you mentioned as table still exists. It seems that you didn't quite understand my last sentence. Don't create/drop/create/drop/create/... table, Oracle doesn't work that way.